# aws cognito user pool social signin linkedin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-amplify

I have implemented the AWS Cognito user pool social sign-in using **Auth0** but it seems very costly so I want to know that, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "costly"?

Comment: @JorgeGarcia what is required for application costs too much so is there any other way/solution to do this?

Comment: what is too much? how much is acceptable?